# Cannot convert Retrofit Response to error custom object twice

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

Why I cannot convert Retrofit Response to object of this class twice:

```
public static class ApiError { //inner class in REST-class
        @SerializedName("error_code")
        private int errorCode;
        @SerializedName("error_description")
        private String message;

        public int errorCode() {
            return errorCode;
        }

        public String message() {
            return message;
        }
    }
```

Convertion:

```
public static ApiError parseError(Response<?> response) {
        Converter<ResponseBody, ApiError> converter =
                retrofit.responseBodyConverter(ApiError.class, new Annotation[0]);

        ApiError error;

        try {
            error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new ApiError();
        }

        return error;
    }
```

So `error2` object has nothing in their fields `errorCode` and `message` But why?

```
REST.ApiError error = REST.parseError(response);
REST.ApiError error2 = REST.parseError(response);
```

I see nothing about this in docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `response.errorBody()` you obtain `ResponseBody` instance, which definition is:

`public abstract class ResponseBody implements Closeable`

That means, that when you try to read the stream (probably by using `public final byte[] bytes()` method), you flush the stream. It is closed therefore cannot be read second time.

**Solution:**

Obtain instance of `Reader` from `ResponseBody` and wrap it into `BufferedStream`:

```
BufferedReader streams = new BufferedReader(response.errorBody().charStream());
```

Then you might call `reset()` on the sream as many often as you like:

```
streams.reset();
```